# Convert Greek Characters to Terminal Hex Font

Tags: c#, globalization

I need to Convert greek characters as charmap terminal font hex value.
[image]

Example how can i convert

```
string test="ΞΥΔΙ";
```

to hex value "\0x8D.......and so on.

If will Convert from String to Hex i'm getting wrong hex value

```
 byte[] ba = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253).GetBytes("ΨΓΣΦ");
        var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
        MessageBox.Show(hexString);
```

Example from character 'Ξ' i'm getting 0xCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close:

1. Change Code Page from *Windows* (Win-**1253**) to *MS DOS* one (**737**)
2. If you want to see codes represented as a string, I suggest using *Linq* and `String.Join`

Something like this:

```
 // Terminal uses MS DOS Code Page which is 737 (not Win-1253)
 byte[] ba = Encoding.GetEncoding(737).GetBytes("ΞΥΔΙ"); 

 // Let's use Linq to print out a test
 var hexString = string.Join(" ", ba.Select(c => $"0x{(int)c:X2}"));

 Console.Write(hexString);
```

Outcome:

```
 0x8D 0x93 0x83 0x88
```

Please, notice that `Ξ` has `0x8D` code.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is actually ok from what I've tested.

I just used the Windows calculator and the Wikipedia 1253 encoding table.

I searched for the 'Ξ' character, and although I'm clueless on Greek characters, a simple search shows that the character indeed matches 0xCE (the font looks funky to me, but the browser seems to like it).

[image]

Comment: But i need to Change it in terminal font hex value.

Comment: @testsc I don't understand what you're asking for

Comment: If i will export it in txt and changing font to terminal i see wrong character

Comment: What does _"changing the font to terminal"_ mean?

Comment: There's not enough context to infer why 'Ξ' is 0x8D in your program, other than you're using the wrong encoding